# my video won't play?

Tags: dreamweaver

I tried a lot but I don't know why it won't play.

```
<html> 
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="player/flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js"> </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div>
     <object codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="320" height="240"> 
              <param name="movie" value="player/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" />
               <param name="salign" value="lt" />
               <param name="quality" value="high" />
               <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
               <param name="FlashVars" 
                value="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&streamName
                =../player/baby.flv&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" />
               <embed src="player/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" 
               flashvars="&MM_ComponentVersion=1&streamName
               =player/baby.flv&autoPlay=false&autoRewind=false" 
               quality="high" scale="noscale" width="320" height="240" 
               name="FlowPlayer" salign="LT" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
               pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
      </object>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do is create a link to your video file like so ...

```
<a 
    href="../player/baby.flv" 
    style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;" 
    id="player">
</a>
```

Then call the following javascript from the flowplayer js file you should be including

```
flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",  {
clip: {

    // these two configuration variables does the trick
    autoPlay: false, 
    autoBuffering: true // <- do not place a comma here  
}
});
```

For my source and more information look here http://flowplayer.org/demos/configuration/index.html

Comment: That should get you going down the right path. There are a ton of other things you can do with Flowplayer all of which are heavily documented on their site. www.flowplayer.com

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I'm running my webpages in wamp 2.1 - localhost as there are some php scripts.

Comment: install firebug in FF check the console, is it throwing any errors? or go to the console in Chrome (ctrl+shift+i) see if its throwing any js errors.